Can I call soap cxf to client service external in the sub route camel?
I run into a problem when I expose a soap service (cxf) and this one in its process must call another external soap service (cxf).
Is there a way to "clean" or should I recreate an exchange? Before the external call?
In the resources directory, I have my two contracts (mine which I expose) and (that of the service which I must call to retrieve data and consolidate the first call).
My client cxf:

@Produces
@SessionScoped
@Named
CxfEndpoint cxfCallExtern()
final CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();

And the call is :

.setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("getdata"))
.setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("http://domainNamespace/v1"))
.setHeader(CxfConstants.DESTINATION_OVERRIDE_URL, simple("http://domainExternal:8081/blabla/blibli"))
.setHeader("SOAPAction",constant("http://domainExternal/blabla/blibli/v1/getdata"))


.to("cxf:bean:cxfCallExtern)

But it dont binding operationName... but I have into /target/generate-code all class from the wsdl client..
I see into properties org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingOperationInfo , have only the first contrat exposed, but not the binding of client service.
Thanks

sorry i use : <quarkus.platform.version>3.4.3</quarkus.platform.version>  and camel core is 4.0.0
